# Does the word 'authored by' imply the non-existence of co-authors?

Tags: academic-writing, word-choice, authorship

In an article I'm co-authoring, I'm about to say the following:

> ... d is the number of articles authored by John Doe ...

But then I thought this would be better:

> ... d is the number of articles authored or co-authored by John Doe ...

Since I thought that the word 'authored' in the first sentence might imply that author John Doe is the sole author of all of the d articles. Am I right? or am I just being too meticulous since this is our first article?

Comment: I believe this is more fit for English Language & Usage, as you are effectively asking what the meaning of a word is and how to use it.

Comment: You may also be able ask this on [academia.SE] who regularly deal with author citations issues if that is your context. Good luck!

Comment: You have now asked the same question on [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/499168/does-the-word-authored-by-imply-the-non-existence-of-co-authors). If you believe that's a better site for it, please delete it from here. (It should only exist on one site.)

Comment: I think there's likely to be a difference between the *general* meaning of "authored" that you might find in a dictionary, and the quite *specific* meaning of the term within the publishing industry or in academic writing. I therefore think our site here is definitely a correct place to ask your question, so I'm voting to leave this question open. While cross-posting is certainly discouraged, there's no *prohibition* of it; [this community-accepted Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069) provides guidance on the subject. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking as an academic and professor, I say you are right. "authored by" implies sole authorship and denies others the credit they are due. Use co-author, or "John Doe, et al" for specific papers. Or if you are talking about a mix and John Doe is the sole author of at least one, then "authored or co-authored by" is appropriate.

Comment: The last case you mentioned is exactly what I'm dealing with, a mix, thanks.